# Increasing zoom level in 3D View QGIS Desktop?

Tags: dem, qgis-3, 3d, zoom, image-mosaic

I would like to increase the zoom level for my mosaic raster image in the 3D View of QGIS Desktop 3.4.4. I made a mosaic out of four raster images downloaded through the STRM-plugin for DEM data. Whenever I zoom in the 3D View, it seems as if the maximum size for me to zoom in is very small, so that I cannot increase it any further than this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to increase the zoom level for this image in the 3D View?

Could my problems stem from the image being a mosaic image?